# distinct & count grouping distinct items?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create one query to select some data. I need to select them only as DISTINCT but count each group of items inside each container eg

results:
CATEGORY EMAIL

1. Jo1    user1@www.com
2. Jo1    user2@www.com
3. Jo1    user3@www.com
4. Jo2    user4@www.com
5. Jo2    user5@www.com

what I need:
Jo1   3 -> count unique users
Jo2   2 -> count unique users

I can do it with distinct to split them but can't find a way of counting separate groups. `SELECT count(DISTINCT CATEGORY)` ... counting all users.

Thnanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should be `COUNT(DISTINCT)`ing `email` not `category`:

```
SELECT `CATEGORY`, COUNT(DISTINCT `EMAIL`)
FROM the_table
GROUP BY `CATEGORY`
;
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out similar query with GROUP BY and is fine. I forgot to add I'm having problem when add LIKE '%%' statement for category. I'm getting only one row as a result. Is there any way of adding like and still split categories ?

Comment: Ok, I've used HAVING instead of LIKE at the end. Looks like it helps.

Comment: @Adam you'd have to be a little more specific about how you were `LIKE`ing